# git svn ignore bad commit while fetching (pretending it wasn't a merge)

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

My question is similar to this one: [With "git svn", Can I Ignore Specific Git Commits While Fetching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430645/git-svn-can-i-ignore-some-svn-commits-while-fetching-into-git)

I'm using git-svn with a standard svn repo:

```
trunk
branches
tags
```

Then a co-worker accidentally branched the root into a project branch, so it looked like this:

```
trunk
branches
   badProject
      trunk
      branches
      tags
tags
```

If the branch had died, I'd probably be able to use `--ignore-paths` to ignore it

However, having realized the error, the developer committed changes to the bad project in   `/branches/badProjects/trunk` and later merged this into `/trunk`

git-svn fetch dies. How can I pretend this bad branch didn't happen?

Is there a way to convince git-svn that there wasn't a branch and treat the merge into trunk as if it was a normal checkin instead of a merged branch?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we had initial branch creation as 666, a checkin at 800, and a merge at 1000
I managed to get it to work as follow:

```
git svn reset -r665
git svn fetch -rBASE:665
git svn fetch -r667:799
git svn fetch -r801:999
git svn fetch -r1000 --no-follow-parent
git svn fetch -r1001:HEAD
```

Line 1 and 2 ensure that I back out to before the bad commit.

Line 3 and 4 pull in changes for the revisions that weren't the bad branch

Line 5 with `--no-follow-parent` gets the merge without acknowledging it was actually a merge

Line 6 gets the rest.