# Skip an SVN Commit in SVN to Git Conversion?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am doing a large migration from SVN to Git. This migration goes back through about four years of history. I am able to successfully push commits up to a certain date, (Nov 11). On this date, there was one commit that pushed a 7GB file, and in the following commit, this file was removed (it appears to have been a mistake).

Git throws an error when attempting to push this enormous commit, and I cannot get past it. Is there any way simply skip that commit? My current process is to checkout a specific commit, push it, and repeat. I did this to find the error that I am currently facing.

Thanks for all advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git svn.. Can I ignore some svn commits while fetching into git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430645/git-svn-can-i-ignore-some-svn-commits-while-fetching-into-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you just `git svn fetch` until the commit immediately before the bad commit you want to skip, then fetch beginning at the commit immediately after the bad commit. Keep in mind, skipping a commit will cause problems if other files were created or modified in this commit, and later commits depend on those modifications.

```
git svn fetch -r BASE:<BAD REVISION>
git svn fetch -r <BAD REVISION>:HEAD
```

There's [a great thread on this](https://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-05/msg00171.html) on the main git mailing list. @me_and posted a similar solution to a similar question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11085087/145279) as well.